# SQL Command isnt running (invalid identifier) maybe SYSDATE?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my command to run and I think that it has something to do with the SYSDATE command:

```
CREATE TABLE crimes (
  crime_ID NUMBER(9),
  criminal_ID NUMBER(6),
  classification CHAR(1),
  data_changed DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  status CHAR(2),
  hearing_date DATE,
  appeal_cut_date DATE,
);
```

I get the `ORA-00904`: : `invalid identifier error`. Any fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the last field definition:

```
appeal_cut_date DATE,
```

Get rid of the comma and you'll be fine.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce3ec7bfaf672beaf76153b6142d0ba6)